# Converting Shapefile to GeoJSON - UTM6 and MTM3 versions give bad coordinates

Tags: shapefile, geojson

I am trying to convert SHP to GeoJSON to work with Google Maps API's data layers.

I am working with [ogre](https://ogre.adc4gis.com/) (I also tried [mapshaper](http://mapshaper.org/), but it always give bad coordinates).  When I convert SHP with WGS84 format, the conversion works fine.  However when I try to convert MTM3 and UTM6 SHP formats to GeoJSON, the coordinates are all screwed up.

Bad coordinates example: `{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[642014.75,4911335.859999999],[642005.96,4911335.92],[642005.6600000001,4911380.0600000005],[642003.6200000001,4911405.58] ...`

I notice that on the ogre website, there are optional fields for Source SRS & Target SRS.  Am I suppose to add something there to get UTM/MTM conversions to work?

Comment: what commands are you using?

Comment: @Mapperz Commands?  I'm just uploading the SHP zip file and converting it.

Comment: like skip failure?

Comment: @Mapperz I just tried both 'skip failure' and 'Create Mapbox-compatible file (RFC7946)', both returned the same bad coordinates

Comment: GeoJSON only supports one Coordinate reference system.

Comment: Please specify what exactly is bad about those coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your source data are using some other coordinate system than EPSG:4326 and you need to get GeoJSON according to current standard https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946 you must give the EPSG codes for both the input and output data.

For MTM3 the code to use seems to be 32183  http://georepository.com/crs_32183/NAD83-MTM-zone-3.html and for UTM zone 6 it may be 32606 http://georepository.com/crs_32606/WGS-84-UTM-zone-6N.html. The output code is 4326. Alternatively check the "Create Mapbox-compatible file (RFC7946)" box which should change the output automatically into EPSG:4326.

As mentioned, the GeoJSON standard defines that coordinates are expressed as WGS84 long-lat coordinates but other coordinates systems can be used if needed:

> However, where all involved parties have a prior arrangement,
> alternative coordinate reference systems can be used without risk of
> data being misinterpreted.

If support for other coordinate systems is needed it is common to follow the older GeoJSON specification http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html.

Ogre is a simple web client for the GDAL utility program ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. If you want better control for the conversion I recommend to install GDAL on your own computer and run ogr2ogr locally. The detail of the GDAL GeoJSON driver are documented in http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html.